# Could not find PlayHaven SDK apk

Tags: android, eclipse, playhaven

I am building a test app in android that uses playhaven sdk to do cross-promotions. I have integrated the sdk by adding playhaven sdk as project library and adding this library in my test app. I changed the relative path of playhaven library in project.properties of my test app to absolute path because library import error was arising.
Now library import in the project is fine, added following code in onCreate()

```
try {
        PlayHaven.configure(getApplicationContext(), token, secret);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
(new OpenRequest()).send(getApplicationContext());
Windowed dialog = new Windowed(getApplicationContext(), "placement_tag");
dialog.show();
```

when i run this app in emulator it gives an error.

**Could not find playhaven-android-sdk.apk!**

**UPDATE**

Logcat gives

**java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.playhaven.android.PlayHaven**

Help is really Appreciated.

Regards,

Comment: Found the Problem. It was the wrong import. I had to add through Project Properties>Android>Library
What i did was to add from Java BuildPath